# Using Join Field more than once in ArcGIS Pro ModelBuilder?

Tags: modelbuilder, editing, arcgis-pro, attribute-joins, zonal-statistics

I have a model where I'm trying to aggregate the zonal sums of a set of ~30 rasters into attributes on a shapefile of country boundaries.  Ideally my model would create a new field in the country shapefile named raster1, and give the sum of values in raster1 within each feature.

This is my current implementation: [image]

Yesterday, this model worked as intended, but revealed that I didn't have the NoData values properly configured on my 'production' rasters, resulting in Zonal Stats not ignoring NoData values.  I configured the inputs, ran a couple iterations manually, and things were working correctly.  But now when I run it, It fails on the second Join Field.  It says the table is not editable and Join Field fails to execute.

I still don't understand how ArcGIS Pro handles editing/locking.  I've made sure that the table does not have outstanding edits prior to running the model, but it hangs anyway.

An additional problem with this model is that the joins are all awkward variations of 'Sum' (the field name I'm joining).  I'm not sure how to incorporate the Name object from Iterate Rasters into the Join Field step so that the fields are named properly, but if anyone has input on that, that would also be great.